# ForeignKey dateField result none

Tags: python, django, django-views

here my model and views

models.py

```
class ClosingDate(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_from = models.DateField()

class Salary(models.Model):
    ...
    closingdate = models.ForeignKey(ClosingDate, related_name='closingdate')
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Views.py

```
class CreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('employee', 'closingdate')
    model = models.Salary

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.desc = str(self.object.closingdate.date_from)
        self.object.save()

        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

iam trying to get datefield and post it into str, i do with `str(self.object.closingdate.date_from)` but result none. but when i try take the name `str(self.object.closingdate.name)` its working as well.

whats wrong with my code?... what should i do?... thank you!

Comment: use strftime method of python date class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert `datetime` into string that way, you should use the attribute `strftime`.
[See the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

```
date.strftime(format)
```

It Returns a string representing the date, controlled by an explicit format string.:

```
self.object.closingdate.date_from.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Comment: got an error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: before using it , make sure that `self.object.closingdate.date_from` has datetitme value with `if statement`